# Slack automatic Login

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, electron, slack-api, slack

Let's brainstorm for a bit. I have an electron app, which does a bunch of stuff, and what i want to do is to have my users sign in to Slack more easily.

The ideal solution would be to present my users with a button which would open up Slack Web App, and log them in automatically to Slack via some OAuth black magic.

Of course the ideal solution does not seem possible (maybe it is, and i am an idiot?). So i started wondering about different types of logins my users could have, iframes, signin with slack etc. But none seem to solve my problem.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Are they signing in to slack? or using their slack account to sign in to your app?

Comment: Have you checked out the magic "Sign in with Slack" button? 
https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack

Comment: The idea is to sign them in **into Slack chat webapp** in one click. I am open for any suggestions. The app is still in the planning, so any suggestions that would have the desired effect are possible, even using the sign in with slack button. But from what i have read in the documentation, the button allows users to log into my app with their slack credentials. Not to connect my app to slack, and thereby automatize the login process, which is the desired effect.